# MATLAB to C-code

Tags: c, matlab, cell-array, codegen

I am following MathWorks guide to converting MATLAB code to C-code. 
The first step is to  enter

> %#codegen

after every function that I want converted to C-code, however doing so has given me the following prompt on the code below.

```
function lanes=find_lanes(B,h, stats)
% Find the regions that look like lanes
%#codegen

lanes = {};
l=0;
    for k = 1:length(B)
    metric = stats(k).MajorAxisLength/stats(k).MinorAxisLength;
    %testlane(k);
    %end
    %function testlane(k)
        coder.inline('never');
        if metric > 5 & all(B{k}(:,1)>100)
            l=l+1;
            lanes(l,:)=B(k);
        else
            delete(h(k))
        end
    end
end
```

around the curly braces:

> code generation only supports cell operations for "varargin" and
>   "varargout"

Another prompt says

> Code generation does not support variable "lanes" size growth through indexing

where *lanes* is mentioned for the second time.

The input Arguments for the function are:

**B** - Is the *output* of the **bwboundaries Image Processing toolbox function**. It is a *P-by-1 cell array*, where P is the number of objects and holes. Each cell in the cell array contains a Q-by-2 matrix. Each row in the matrix contains the row and column coordinates of a boundary pixel. Q is the number of boundary pixels for the corresponding region.

**h** -  plots the boundaries of the objects with a green outline while  being a matrix of size 1 X length(B), holding  the values of the boundaries like so like so:

```
h(K)=plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);//boundary(:,1) - Y coordinate, boundary(:,2) - X coordinate.
```

**stats** - *19x1 struct array* acquired using the **regionprops** function from the Image Processing toolbox with fields:
    MajorAxisLength and
    MinorAxisLength (of the object)

I would really appreciate any input you can give in helping me clear this error. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Code generation is severely limited it what it can handle.  You might want the MATLAB compiler instead (http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/), to package some MATLAB code into a deployable standalone application.

Answer (score 5):

Few points about your code generation -

1. Only a subset of functions in MATLAB and Image Processing Toolbox support code generation - [Image Processing Toolbox support for code generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/code-generation.html).
2. Cell arrays do not support code generation yet - [Cell array support](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html).
3. In your code, it seems like your variable is growing i.e. the initial size of the array is not able to support your workflow. You should follow [code generation for variable sized inputs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/defining-variable-size-data-for-code-generation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error i.e. *code generation does not support variable size growth through indexing*. Inside my for loop I had a statement as such which had the same error:

```
y(i) = k;
```

I introduced a temporary storage variable u and modified my code to:

```
u = y;
u(i) = k;
y = u;
```

I suggest you do the same for your variable *lanes.*